# Know the row & column number of a range

Tags: vba, excel

I need make an Excel function that finds a value in a `range(range1)` , and when finds the value make a product with others `ranges(2,3,4)`, like this:

```
function PRODUCT_IF_RANGE=(obj as string,range1 as range,range2 as 
range,range3 as range,range4 as range) as string
```

the "ranges" not necessarily shares the same "sheet" and the output type of the function is "string" cause I need that notation.

My problem is how I can knows the `sheet(name or index)`, first an last row, and first and last column of a range? With that I can iterate the range and makes the function runs, like:

```
dim row11 as integer    'first row´s number of range1
dim row12 as integer    'last  row´s number of range1
dim column11 as integer 'first column´s number of range1
dim column12 as integer 'first column´s number of range1
........
for i=row11 to row12
for j=column11 to column12
if sheets(sheetr1).cells(i,j)=obj then
.......
next j
next i
........
........
```

So I just need know the value(number) of first and last row, first ans last column asd the sheet of a range.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: Why not use `Range.Find` instead of iterating?

Comment: because i don´t know how use it, i try but i am rush with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all that information from the `Range` objects themselves.

```
Set sheet1 = range1.Worksheet
row11 = range1.Row
row12 = range1.Row + range1.Rows.Count 'Start row + the number of rows in the range
column11 = range1.Column
column12 = range1.Column + range1.Columns.Count 'Start col + the number of cols in the range
```

Comment: Thanks mate i continue with the development  of the function and i will knows you that its works.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `Set sheet1 = range1.Worksheet`.  You need the `Set` keyword since it's an object reference.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
With range1
    range1SheetName = .Parent.Name
    Set range1Sheet= .Parent

    row11 = .Rows(1).Row
    row12 = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row

    column11 = .Columns(1).Column
    column12 = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
End With
```

But you can also directly iterate through rows or columns

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell in range1.Columns(1).Cells ‘iterate through first column cells -> iterate through rows
    Msgbox cell.Row
Next

For Each cell in range1.Rows(1).Cells ‘iterate through first row cells -> iterate through columns
    Msgbox cell.Column
Next

For Each cell in range1.Columns ‘iterate through columns
    Msgbox cell.Address ‘ cell is the entire current column
Next

For Each cell in range1.Rows ‘iterate through rows
    Msgbox cell.Address ‘ cell is the entire current row
Next
```